# Как исправить ошибку member reference base type 'AATree' (aka '_AATreeNode *') is not a structure or union

Tags: c

Вот исходники:
AATree.h

```
#pragma once

typedef struct _AATreeNode
{
    int             key;
    int             level;
    _AATreeNode    *left;
    _AATreeNode    *right;
}AATreeNode, *AATree;

void aat_insertData  (AATree *, int);
void aat_deleteData  (AATree *, int);
AATree* aat_searchData  (AATree*,   int);
void aat_deleteTree  (AATree *);
void aat_printTree   (FILE   *, AATree, int);
```

сама функция:

```
AATree* aat_searchData(AATree* bst, int key)
{
    AATree*  i;
    i = bst;
    while (i != NULL)
    {
        if (key == i->key)
        {
            printf("нашел %d\n", i->key);
            return i;
        }
        if (key > i->key)
            i = i->right;
        else
            i = i->left;
    }
    return i;                                       // Not found.
}
```

Comment: так как вы создали тип `AATree` == `struct _AATreeNode *` равным указателю, то добавление ещё одной звёздочки `AATree*` приводит к типу `struct _AATreeNode * *`. И идёт несоответствие типов. Измените везде запись `AATree*` -> `AATree`

Answer (score 0):

Если уже си, тогда структуру нужно объявлять по правилам си, где то так (обратите внимание на `struct`) :

```
typedef struct _AATreeNode
{
    int             key;
    int             level;
    struct  _AATreeNode    *left;
    struct  _AATreeNode    *right;
}AATreeNode, *AATree;
```

Теперь к собственно ошибке. Что такое `i`? - это указатель на `AATree`. А `AATree` - это в свою очередь указатель на структуру. Поэтому, когда Вы пишете `i->key`  компилятор недоумевает, так как `i` - это `struct _AATreeNode**` (да, две звездочки) и так нельзя. Но можно вот так `(*i)->key`. С строкой вида `i = i->right;` чуть сложнее. Где то так `i = &(*i)->right;`